How to access the item inside the hash table in one step C++
I studied hash tables in C++ and learned that there are two types of representation of hash tables, one using a tree and another type using an array from a linked list.
Since the hash table provides me with the fastest addition and fastest access, as it requires only one step, except for some cases in which the hash result for more than one key equals one index in the array, then I search within the linked list.
My question is, how can access be represented in one step and addition in one step using a tree, knowing that the tree is non-linear and does not have an index, and searching in it requires a number of steps, and the only case in which one step is needed is when the value is the root.
Do I need more explanation for this?
I read a lot but I didn't understand

the best you can get with a tree structure is O(logN).

Generally, dictionaries can be implemented as trees or as hash tables. Hash tables are usually not implemented as trees (unless you implement the buckets as trees which might have some advantages over lists, but the buckets themselves are basically elements in an array).

there are two types of representation of hash tables, one using a tree and another type using an array from a linked list. No. There are two types of associate arrays a.k.a. dictionaries. One is a tree (std::map), one is a hash table (std::unordered_map). A hash table does not typically use a tree structure. The hash table is typically built using a linked list and an array.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Minor point: this has nothing to do with C++; the question is about the algorithm, and implementing it in any language would have the same issues.

"I [...] learned that there are two types of representation of hash tables, one using a tree and [...]" -- Could you provide a reference for this? This question appears to be based on a false premise. (That is, you're asking how can a false claim be true.)

@Homer Small addition : The basic structure of a hash-table usually isn't a list, but a contiguous piece of memory containing buckets (implementation details of buckets/solving collissions is very implementation dependent and may involve lists).

@JaMiT You are right there are tree-based maps and hash-key based maps (hash-tables)

You will need to use a plain array if you want single step access to your data.  One kind of hash-table takes your key into a function to generate the index, then uses the index to fetch the key.  More than a single step.  The access time gets worse if the hash table is implemented with a linked list.  If you fast access, you'll need an array.  Other data structures are designed to speed up the search for an item.

@PepijnKramer I said linked list and array, not just list. I'm referring to this structure in particular: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230808-00/?p=108572 The question is also tagged [C++] so I'm implicitly referring to std::unordered_map, which is pretty much guaranteed to use a linked list, not open addressing.

Thank you very much, your answers explained the matter correctly to me
